# network optimization scvmm

Tags: hyper-v, failovercluster

I'm configuring a new 2012 R2 Hyper-V fail over cluster.  I have two identical hosts. I have successfully validated the cluster.  I was testing migration using SCVMM and noticed that network optimization isn't checked.  On my Guest Nic team, I've disabled all the offload options on the NIC and VMQ is enabled.  What am I missing?  I have two Nics teamed for the guests, 1 live migration Nic, and 1 management Nic.  Those four Nics are all 1GB.  I have two 10GB Nics for iSCSI on each host.  Live migration works, but I'm just wondering why I don't have that pretty green check mark.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqMbW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your host NIC(s) don't have VMQ or don't have VMQ enabled.

Comment: Virtual Machine Queues is enabled.

Comment: Yes, but do the host NICs have hardware support for VMQ?

Comment: I was referring to the host NICs.  I added a screen shot of the host NIC's VMQ settings.